# NodeJS HTTPS request via bluebird and request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, promise

I am making a https call but getting nothing in my console. Please help. Here is my code. Please let me know if there is an alternative way to approach this.

I am trying to fetch all servers by extracting server uris and then fetch properties of those server uris. There are about 1000 servers. Using promise and request to accomplish the task. It'd be a great help if someone can guide me in the right direction.

**Code**
/*MODULES*/

```
var express = require('express');
var rp = require('request-promise');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var app = express();

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
};

/*PROMISES*/
fetchAllUsers() 
    .then(function(userData) {
        console.log("This is USERDATA ", userData);
    });

function fetchAllUsers() {

    var username = 'username123',
    password = 'pass123',
    role = 'Read-Only',
    url_host = 'https://link.com:10843';

    var url1 = url_host + '/type/PropertySetClasses/SystemObject/Server/?username=' + username +  '&password=' + password + '&role=' + role;

    var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString("base64");

    return rp.get({
        uri: url1,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': auth,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        transform: function(body, res) {
            // if(!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
                res= JSON.parse(body);
                return res;
            // }
        }
    });
}
```

**Console**
"THIS IS USERDATA"

[image]

This is where I expect the list of server uris.

Comment: Just saying, your `auth` construction tries to access `username` and `password` before they are initialised. Use `let` instead of `var` to get an exception for such mistakes.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` takes only a single parameter. Try `console.log("This is USERDATA ", JSON.stringify(userData));` (or no `JSON.stringify` at all).

Comment: Are you getting the `console.log` from the `transform` callback?

Comment: @bergi I will do that once I am around my computer. I am not getting anything back on transform either.

Comment: None of these fixed it.

Comment: So what exactly is happening now, what logs are you getting (and are you getting the one from `transform` at all)? Can you update your post with the fixed code, please? And why does your `transform` callback not return anything?

Comment: Please see the code. I have added a snippet of my console. I don't understand why transform is not returning anything back. It returns back if I use request.get. With this code I get nothing.

Comment: Maybe `servers` is `undefined`. Can you add a string to the logging statement?

Comment: I added strings. It's not showing anything in the log at all from transform.

Comment: Maybe the `if` condition doesn't match. Can you check (using a debugger or more logs)?

Comment: See the updated code. I am getting a promise back. it looks like request promise doesn't handle errors.